# How can I both refresh the page and add a few arguments to it?

Tags: php, redirect, routes

Here is my code:

```
header("Refresh:0");
```

As you know it redirects the current page to itself *(in other word it refreshes the page)*. Ok I also need to add some arguments like these at the end of the url:

```
?arg1=value1&arg2=value2
```

Doing that is possible?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to do? It is unclear what you are actually trying to pull off here.